# Reloading the Main Activity : Navigation Stops working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my main activity I want to reload the activity as I want the app to reload since the user is logging in.
I dont know if thats a good idea but when I am validating the user credentials and calling these lines of code in my main activity.

```
var viewGroup = (ViewGroup)
    ((ViewGroup)FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content)).GetChildAt(0);
viewGroup.RemoveAllViews();
Finish();
StartActivity(Intent);
```

WHat happens is that the screen flashes and the activity is loaded again from scratch(that doesnt not look mature). The problem is the app works fine but the navigation stops working when I call

`ShowViewModel(SomeViewModel);`

I know I am doing something wrong, or may be not following the best practise here. My only intent is to reload the application setting the flags and load the users profile making the user feel as if the user was already logged in.

**Version:** 4.1.4

**Platform:** Xamarin Android

Comment: Why are you `RemoveAllViews()` ?

Comment: thats because I need to reload everything fresh with UI changes in hamburger menu.

Comment: Any errors in the output? Stacktrace?

Comment: When you finish the activity and start it again, the view is recreated as Activity's onCreate method is called...

Comment: So solution to my problem is would be? I tried commenting the removeAllViews() and nothing changed. I guess mvvmcross framework is coming somewhere in between and doing some kind of reference caching.

Comment: Did you try to clear all navigation back stack and showiewmodel<mainiewmodel> (or whatever your first view model is called) ?

Comment: No I did not clear the back stack. So should I call the support fragment manager and clear the stack or is there any other way of doing it through the MVVM cross framework. @hugo

Comment: Try to implement the folowing piece of code  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/viewmodel--to-viewmodel-navigation#how-do-i-remove-views-and-viewmodels-from-the-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation breaks because you're trying to handle navigation on your own instead of letting MvvmCross do it for you.

As you can see in the [default Android presenter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/79de539d478734b5eaf110a9efa86c71b99d2fa2/MvvmCross/Droid/Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs), the method that receives an `Intent` is not public. When you call `ShowViewModel`, an instance of `IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator` (more specifically [this implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/Droid/Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L124-L141) if you didn't override it) is called and it creates the `Intent` for you.

Regarding your problem, I'd question whether you really need to recreate your entire View. If you don't, you can easily create a subclass of `MvxPresentationHint` and do whathever you like using the `ChangePresentation` method. This is a clean and cross platform solution (since the code that triggers the presentation change is on the shared code area)

If you really need to recreate the entire view, you should use `ShowViewModel` from your ViewModel when needed instead of calling `StartActivity` on your own. I'd create a helper method like `ShowViewModelAndRemoveSelfFromBackstack` in order to show your the ViewModel again and prevent the user from returning to the old one. Such behaviour can be achieved by using [parameter/presentation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxViewModelRequest.cs#L33-L34)  values and treating them accordingly in your Presenter